# DB2 v8 Nullable Foreign Keys

Tags: foreign-keys, db2

Does DB2 version 8 z/OS support nullable foreign keys?

For example, a foreign key on a person table to the supervisor table (where some people do not have supervisors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, it should be possible to have a foreign key that is nullable in DB2 for z/OS v8.  See the **insert**, **update**, and **delete** rules for these details:

**insert rule**
A nonnull insert value of the foreign key must match some value of the parent key of the parent table. The value of a composite foreign key is null if any component of the value is null.

**update rule**
A nonnull update value of the foreign key must match some value of the parent key of the parent table. The value of a composite foreign key is treated as null if any component of the value is null.

**delete rule**
Controls what happens when a row of the parent table is deleted. The choices of action, made when the referential constraint is defined, are RESTRICT, NO ACTION, CASCADE, or SET NULL. SET NULL can be specified only if some column of the foreign key allows null values.

Site reference: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref%2Frcncrfi.htm

DB2 v8 Foreign Key Clause reference (also notes that nulls are allowed): http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/c0004981.htm

Answer (score 1):

It would be quicker to try it than study the documentation, which will be removed from the IBM web site after January 2013.

Here's part of the explanation of the [CREATE TABLE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref/rctbl.htm) statement.

> The foreign key of the referential constraint is composed of the identified columns. |Each column-name must |be an unqualified name that identifies a column of the table except |a LOB, ROWID, or security label column, and the same column must not |be identified more than once. The number of identified columns must not exceed 64, and the sum of their length attributes must not exceed 255 minus the number of columns that allow null values. The referential constraint is a duplicate if the FOREIGN KEY and parent table are the same as the FOREIGN KEY and parent table of a previously defined referential constraint. The specification of a duplicate referential constraint is ignored with a warning.

So yes, a foreign key can contain one or more nullable columns.